# Deploying a websocket server on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, websocket, google-cloud-run

I would like to serve a webrtc signalling server, using websockets, on Google Cloud Run.

I took a simple server implementation from the internet, and uploaded it to Cloud Run, the metrics say it's up.

However, whenever I try connecting to it via:

```
 uwsc ...run.app:9080/
 uwsc ws://...run.app
 uwsc wss://...run.app
```

I'm getting an `Error connecting to websocket`. For the two latter connection attempts, the logs on GCP say that the webserver responded with status 302 and 101, respectively. For the wss one, the logs also show that the connection was established, but then immediately closed, with code 1006.

Server implementation:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: process.env.PORT });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log(`Got a new connection`);
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`Got message ${message}.`);
    });
    ws.on('close', (code, reason) => {
        console.log(`Connection with peer closed `
            + `with reason ${code}: ${reason}`);
    });
    ws.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ws": ">=8.0.0"
  }
}
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Soo, it turned out that it was the tool for testing the websocket connection: `uwsc` which was broken/not supporting encrypted traffic. After changing to [wscat](https://github.com/websockets/wscat), I started to see the responses.